# Most efficient way to apply a dynamic filter over a large 3-d image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am working with DICOM images in python, which are series of 2-d images (512x512x160 could be typical) representing a CT scan. I am working on an algorithm which downsamples in the z-axis by an integer ratio, producing an image like 512x512x80 (or 512x512x40 etc.).

As an example, going from z=160 to z=80 means that origimg[x,y,z] and origimg[x,y,z+1] will be used to calculate the value for newimg[x,y,z]. The trick is that I have a weighting function which (linearly) defines a mapping between pixel intensity and weight. The resulting value of newimg[x,y,z] is a linear combination of origimg[x,y,z], origimg[x,y,z+1]... origimg[x,y,z+n] (where n is the downsampling ratio), but the value of the weights is dependent on the values of origimg[x,y,z] etc.

I have a naive implementation of this algorithm (no threading), but the runtime is exceedingly slow (10+ minutes), where I need it to be much faster (hopefully <15sec if not better). I am wondering if anyone would have any suggestions on how to do this in the most efficient way possible. Should I write this in C and wrap the code in Python? Will stock Python threading be enough (I am in 2.7 but could port to 3)? Is there some built-in in ITK or scikit that might help?

Edit: Including code

```
r = int(newThickness/self.sliceThickness)
    newdarray = np.zeros([int(ceil(self.numSlices/r)), self.currMatrixSize, self.currMatrixSize])
    ind = 0
    for i in xrange(newdarray.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(newdarray.shape[1]):
            for k in xrange(newdarray.shape[2]):
                weights = []
                Wt = 0
                for x in range(r):
                    if ind+x < self.currdarray.shape[0]:
                        v = self.currdarray[ind+x,j,k]
                        w = self.getWeightValue(v)
                        Wt += w
                        weights = weights + (w*v)
                newdarray[i,j,k] = sum(weights)/Wt
        ind +=r
```

Comment: Questions like these are much easier to answer if you have some example code

Comment: I've added code. However, I'm not looking for subtle refinements on my code but instead just a direction to take for improvements

Comment: Thanks Sean. I understand. I'm just trying to increase your chances of getting a worthwhile answer

Comment: What is `self.getWeightValue`? Is there a chance you could rewrite it to take a full 3D array as input and produce a full 3D array as output? Other than that one, I don't see a reason to loop over `i`, `j`, and `k`. Numpy has indexing and element-wise operators that would do exactly what you do here. Rewrite `weights = weights + (w*v)` as `weights += w*v`, and it becomes clear you only need a loop over `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Most people use [minc](https://github.com/BIC-MNI/minc-toolkit-v2) for this kind of thing. For your problem, you need `mincresample`:

http://bic-mni.github.io/man-pages/man/mincresample.html

It's mostly a command-line tool, but there do seem to be some py bindings.